# How to speed up the loading of data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I've got a DataGridView control, which is to hold around 100,000 records.

It's currently taking around 10 seconds or so to populate ~100k records (and nothing would be happening in this time). The records are not being populated from a database, but rather manually.

Since it does not support paging, is there a control which has similar functionality and supports paging? Or is there any way to load data even faster?

Comment: What do you mean by "not being populated from a database, but rather manually"?

Comment: DataGridView may not support paging, but you can load it page by page. Just add 2 - 3 buttons.

Comment: The data is generated within my application itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution: Use a standard DataGridView and add buttons to load different sections of your data source at a time.

[A great and simple example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/211551/A-Simple-way-for-Paging-in-DataGridView-in-WinForm)

Comment: This seems like the best approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Virtual Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171622.aspx).  This allows you to load data as needed

You can read how to implement it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624.aspx).